# regex html to get ride of <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working on a microsite that displays photos along with text (a person, and a quote from this person).

The guys I'm working with sent a me a batch of .htm files that I converted to html (around 300)

I'm loading the photo and the text using jQuery `.load()`

This is all working fine but inside their text they inserted `<br>` which is displayed when the text is loaded.  I want to get ride of them with a regex.

What I did is the following:

```
var string = $('#lightbox_text').html();
var regex = string.replace(/textoreplace/g, ' ');
$('#lightbox_text').html(regex);
```

The problem is that inside the .htm the bit I want to get ride of is looking like this:

```
&lt;<span class=SpellE><span class=GramE>br</span></span>&gt;<o:p></o:p</span>
```

I don't know how to handle this... I tried doing this:

```
var regex = string.replace(/&lt;<span class=SpellE><span class=GramE>br<\/span><\/span>&gt;/g, ' ');
```

but that doesn't work... don't know what I should do about it, regex are quite confusing to me.

Comment: one other approach ... use IDE to find/replace across many files and get rid of problem permanently. Can do a whole directory in one command

Comment: @charlietfl Not a bad idea at all, something with grep and sed

Comment: @jdphenix my IDE will show me all occurrences.. can verify first, then run replace

Comment: or send the files back and say ... "what the $&*#" !

Comment: @charlietfl : Im thinking about it... haha. 
Yes, using sed was my only working solution. However this method has it owns issues: when using sed I can find and replace the string by a blank space or "" : /find//g or /find/ /g doesn't work... only /find/-/g did work but I don't any other letter/special character to replace the <br>

Comment: i'm sure it does have issues like "**br**andy is good"

Comment: sorry, early post, I've updated my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found my solution using Charlietfl advice to modify sources instead of regex. I already had this in mind but using sed was not giving the expected results as I wasn't able to "find" and "replace" with blank space or even just remove them.

```
sed -i 's/THIS/THAT/g' /path/to/files*.file_format
```

in my case the following did work:

```
LC_CTYPE=C sed -i 's/&lt;<span class=SpellE><span class=GramE>br</span></span>&gt;<o:p></o:p></span>/-/g' /path/to/files*.html
```

but replacing `<br>` with `"-"` wasn't the idea. having `""` or `" "` instead of the "-" didn't work at all for me.

Note: if anyone knows more about sed it would be much appreciated to explain why blank spaces doesn't work.

With this in mind, I find an alternative solution that would first consist in converting the file from `.htm` to `.html` using batch `textutils`command line.

```
textutil -convert html ~/path/to/files/*.htm
```

this converted the "freaking" 
 line from this:

```
&lt;<span class=SpellE><span class=GramE>br</span></span>&gt;<o:p></o:p></span>
```

to this:

```
&lt;br&gt;
```

and this is the dream.
then a simple regex can finish the job:

```
      var string = $('#lightbox_text').html();
      var regex = string.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/gi, ' ');
      $('#lightbox_text').html(regex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, why not just use what it exposes to manipulate the DOM?

Your comments indicate you're getting the HTML as a text representation. That's fine:

```js
var htmlText = '<p>Some text</p><br><br><br><p>Some text</p>',
  $htmlText = $(htmlText);


$('#output').append($htmlText);
$('#output br').remove(); 
console.log($('#output')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

If you look at the console output, you'll be able to see the string representation of the HTML with the `<br>` elements removed.

Comment: <br> are within the text (from a word I assume) that was saved as html... so this doesn't apply unfortunately.

Comment: @SKYnine You could feed the text representation to jQuery, remove the `<br>` elements, and get it back out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a RegExp object, then use that in the `string.replace()` method.

```
var regex = new RegExp('&lt;<span class=SpellE><span class=GramE>br</span></span>&gt;<o:p></o:p</span>', 'g');
var stringNoBr = string.replace(regex, '')
```

Comment: Tried this but it had no effect. This is crazy stupid haha... it works with any other word. If I only use "&lt;" in my regex, I only have "br>" in the end, showing it works. The problem is with the full string. I made sure it was the exact same copy past from the source document.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it.  There's a log of what was replaced. You can check it for false matches and adjust the regexp if needed.

```
var str = "hello&lt;<span class=SpellE><span class=GramE>br</span></span>&gt;<o:p></o:p</span> world";

str = str.replace(/&lt;<.*?>br<.*?>&gt;<o:p><\/o:p<\/span>/g, function(m){
  console.log("replaced: " + m);
  return "";
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works. The full string is replaced. However, using a string.replace(str, ""); has no effect...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than put the unwanted html in the DOM then remove it from the DOM... can switch out using `load()` with `$.get` and remove the unwanted stuff before insertion

```
$.get(url, function(resp){
    var $tmp = $('<div>').append(resp).find('br').remove();
    $('#yourTaregtElementId').html( $tmp).html());
});
```

Alternate CSS solution:

```
.some-class br { display:none}
```

Comment: the problem is the <br> arent compiled. They came from the word document itself. I asked for the guys Im working with to send me the text in an html form, and to add <br> markup for line break. 

the problem is that instead of using a text editor they went for using word. Now I got 300 files so Im trying to save the day instead of processing all the sources again.